# Django Unit test cases

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

Whats the best way to write django unit test cases that include database changes like changing status of an entity???
For Eg:- 
I have different test cases where status of an entity changes on the basis of different action from users that causes changes on databases level.

Whats the best approach to deal with test cases for such operations.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if action==1:
        Entity.last_status= Entity.status
        Entity.status = 1
        Entity.save()
    elif action == 2:
        Entity.last_status = Entity.status
        Entity.status = 2
        Entity.save()
```

and so on...!!! –

Comment: plz add some code

Comment: def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         if action==1:
            Entity.last_status= Entity.status
            Entity.status = 1
            Entity.save()
        elif action == 2:
            Entity.last_status = Entity.status
            Entity.status = 2
            Entity.save()
  and so on...!!!

Comment: edit your question and format your code

Comment: Is `action` a request parameter?

Comment: yes it will come in post request

Answer (score 0):

Hi Django have plenty of TestCase object for testing this purpose :

A small class exemple :

```
import unittest
from django.test import Client

class SimpleTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_action_1(self):
        # Issue a POST request.
        response = self.client.post('/YOUR_POST_URL/', {'action': 1})
        # Check that the response is 200 OK.
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        # Check the last entry
        last_entry = Entry.objects.last()
        self.assertEqual(last_entry.status, 1)

        response = self.client.post('/YOUR_POST_URL/', {'action': 2})
        # Check that the response is 200 OK.
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)        
        # Check that the response is 200 OK.
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        # Check the last entry
        last_entry = Entry.objects.last()
        self.assertEqual(last_entry.status, 2)   
        self.assertEqual(last_entry.last_status, 1)
```

What this test do ?

He will create an empty database make your migration, issue a `POST` request with parameters `action=1`, we check is the status is 200 (executed without error) and check if we have now in database a `Entry` with `status=1`.
Now we do the same with parameters `action=2` and check now `status` and `last_status`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django's test `Client` as described in MaximeK's answer, or another approach is to call the view directly. You can create the `HttpRequest` object and pass that into the view when you call it.

```
from django.http import HttpRequest

def test_set_entity_status(self):
    # Set up the request
    request = HttpRequest()
    request.method = 'POST'
    request.POST['action'] = 1

    # Call the view function directly
    post(request)

    # Perform the assertions
    last_entity = Entity.objects.last()
    self.assertEqual(last_entity.status, 1)
```